# Package and Procedure Compilation

Tags: sql, oracle, package, oracle-apex, procedure

Struggling for over an hour now... Why won't this compile?

The Body compiles fine:

```
create or replace package body "PKG_CUSTOMER" is

PROCEDURE Create_Customer
(  pr_customer_id  customer.Customer_id%type,
      pr_country customer.country%type,
      pr_first_name  customer.first_name%type,
      pr_last_name  customer.last_name%type, 
      pr_birth_date   customer.birth_date%type,
      pr_customer_type customer.customer_type%type,
      pr_address customer.address%type)

   IS
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO customer (Customer_ID,Country,First_Name,Last_Name,Birth_Date,Customer_Type,Address)
         VALUES(pr_customer_id, pr_country, pr_first_name, pr_last_name, pr_birth_date, pr_customer_type, pr_address);
   END Create_Customer;


   PROCEDURE Delete_Customer(pr_customer_id   customer.customer_id%type) IS
   BEGIN
   DELETE FROM order_line WHERE fk1_order_id IN (SELECT order_id FROM placed_order WHERE fk1_customer_id = pr_customer_id);
   DELETE FROM placed_order WHERE fk1_customer_id = pr_customer_id;
   DELETE FROM customer WHERE customer_id = pr_customer_id;
   END Delete_Customer;


end "PKG_CUSTOMER";​
```

But the specification won't compile:

```
create or replace package PKG_CUSTOMER as

Procedure CREATE_CUSTOMER;
Procedure DELETE_CUSTOMER;

end;​
```

I am getting this error:

```
Compilation failed,line 3 (21:20:46)
PLS-00323: subprogram or cursor 'CREATE_CUSTOMER' is declared in a package specification and must be defined in the package bodyCompilation failed,line 4 (21:20:46)
PLS-00323: subprogram or cursor 'DELETE_CUSTOMER' is declared in a package specification and must be defined in the package body
```

I'm using Oracle APEX.

Comment: "The Body compiles fine:"  You are mistaken.  A package won't compile if its spec is not compiled.  the error message you are getting is the body not compiling because the procedure signature's don't match what's in the spec.

Comment: @APC how can i fix this?

Comment: Justin has provided you with the answer.  But mysteriously it doesn't work for you.  So, who can tell?

Answer (score 5):

The package specification has to provide the complete specification for the procedures that you want to expose.  That includes the parameters.  Assuming that you want to make both of the procedures that you declared in the package available to callers outside of the package

```
create or replace package PKG_CUSTOMER 
as
  Procedure CREATE_CUSTOMER(  
        pr_customer_id  customer.Customer_id%type,
        pr_country customer.country%type,
        pr_first_name  customer.first_name%type,
        pr_last_name  customer.last_name%type, 
        pr_birth_date   customer.birth_date%type,
        pr_customer_type customer.customer_type%type,
        pr_address customer.address%type);
  Procedure DELETE_CUSTOMER(pr_customer_id   customer.customer_id%type);
end;​
```

If your intention is to declare a `CREATE_CUSTOMER` and a `DELETE_CUSTOMER` procedure that each accept 0 arguments, you would need to implement those procedures in the package body as well.

Comment: Hi @Justin Cave, I have just tried that and I get the same errors. My intention IS to pass them parameters evetually through an APEX application.

Comment: @IbrahiemRafiq - What tool are you using?  Are you certain that you are compiling the package specification first?  And then compiling the package body?

Comment: I am using ORACLE APEX and I am certain of doing those things you are saying.

Comment: Some bizzare reason I re tried what you suggested and it worked. thanks

Comment: You *cannot* be getting that error is the declaration of the procedures in the spec and body match exactly.  You just can't.  So please check your source code for typos.